# How to sort strings containing numbers and letters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting

I have a list in the following form:

```
['AK 40', 'AK 35', 'AK 20', '2012',
'2011', '2010', '2009', '2009',
'2007', '2006', '2006', '2005',
'2004', '2003', '2003', '2002']
```

Those years all represent birthyears and groupings of ages.
What I need is to sort them in the following form:

```
['2012', '2011', '2010', ... , '2003', '2002', 'AK 20', 'AK 35', 'AK 40']
```

Basically, the years should be descending, from the youngest person to the oldest. But starting from age twenty they need to be treated differently.

I already tried some `lambda` functions I found here on stackoverflow, but unfortunately none of them worked for me due to the fact that my list contains only strings and is not mixed with integers.

Comment: From your research, you probably already know about the `key=` feature. So try writing a function to use as a key that does what you want. This doesn't have to be a lambda. You can just write a function that tells the sort function what to sort by. For instance, you could have a function that calculates the age of a person from the kinds of strings that you use.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings share the same prefix (`AK` in this case), you can use the following `lambda` function:

```
sort_func = lambda e : -int(e) if e.isdigit() else int(''.join(filter(str.isdigit, e)))

sorted_list = sorted(l, key = sort_func)
```

Where `l` is your initial list, for your example, this outputs:

```
['2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2009', '2007', '2006', '2006', '2005', '2004', '2003', '2003', '2002', 'AK 20', 'AK35', 'AK 40']
```

The above functions sorts first by the year strings (the `-` in `-len(e)` is used to sort them in descending order), then, it sorts the age groups in ascending order by the number after the prefix `AK` (by filtering out anything that's not a digit from the age groups' strings).

Answer (score 0):

```
seq = ['AK 40', 'AK 35', 'AK 20', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2009',
       '2007', '2006', '2006', '2005', '2004', '2003', '2003', '2002']

years = [year for year in seq if year.isdigit()]
aks = [ak for ak in seq if not ak.isdigit()]
years.sort()
aks.sort()
result = years[::-1] + aks
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ['AK 40', 'AK 35', 'AK 20', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2009', '2007', '2006', '2006', '2005', '2004', '2003', '2003', '2002']
```

Short and simple will be

```
sorted_list = sorted(x, key = lambda e : int(e.replace('AK ', '-')), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple sort key:

```
d = ['AK 40', 'AK 35', 'AK 20', '2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2009', '2007', '2006', '2006', '2005', '2004', '2003', '2003', '2002']
new_d = sorted(d, key=lambda x:[1, -1][x.isdigit()]*int(x.split()[-1]))
```

Output:

```
['2012', '2011', '2010', '2009', '2009', '2007', '2006', '2006', '2005', '2004', '2003', '2003', '2002', 'AK 20', 'AK 35', 'AK 40']
```

Comment: Could you shortly explain what this lambda function is doing? I'm relatively new to python and and I am still unfamiliar with these [1, -1] syntaxes. 
``int(x.split()[-1])`` returns the number from ``AK 25`` am I correct? But I don't understand the rest of the function.